# Loading plugin from java application

Tags: java

In my java application, I am trying to load a plugin. My code is:

```
pluginManager = PluginManagerFactory.createPluginManager();
pluginManager.addPluginsFrom(new File("plugins/").toURI());
```

From application, I call

```
dummyPlugin = Application.getPluginManager().getPlugin(DummyPlugin.class);
```

But I get a null for dummyPlugin reference. The jar file is present at the location and the File returns correct path.
The impl class implements dummyPlugin and has @PluginImplementation

I searched but it seems very straight forward with this approach. Am I missing the obvious? Is there any class loader issue?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I am guessing you are using JSPF. Can you edit your question?

Comment: What kind of plugin manager are you using?

Comment: Yes, I am using net.xeoh.plugins.base.PluginManager;

Comment: And if I use pluginManager.addPluginsFrom(new URI("classpath://*")); i run out of memory. i am not sure if plugins are not loaded or the next step getting plugin class from classpath is failing. please help –

Comment: Any inputs, please? My DummyPlugin and DummyPluginImplementation are in different location though. Plugin is in the main project and the plugin classes are inside the jar under plugins dir

Comment: My plugin interface and pluginImpl are in different packages. Could it be a problem? I guess so but no idea how to resolve.